# User object Expressions not working in B2B Commerce LWR site

Tags: salesforce-lightning, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I am new to B2B Commerce LWR site. I have been trying to find the authenticated user details using expressions but I keep getting undefined as value

Can anyone please guide me?

B2B Commerce Undefined issue:
[image: image of error]

I tried `{!User.userId}` but no luck!